# How can I do the same thing but in HTML not JavaScript dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My code enables popping up `alert` dialog at the same time as the elapsed time goes by.

How can I do the same thing but in HTML not JavaScript dialog?

Do I have to do it with something related to AJAX?

Can anyone show me an example, please?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var comments = [{'time':'5','message':'hello! 5 secs has past'},{'time':'10','message':'hello! 10 secs has past'},{'time':'30','message':'hello! 30 secs has past'}];

    $('#video').on('timeupdate',function(e){
        showComments(this.currentTime);
    });

    function showComments(time){
        var comments = findComments(time);
        $.each(comments,function(i,comment){
            alert(comment.message);
        });
    }

    function findComments(time){
        return $.grep(comments, function(item){
          return item.time == time.toFixed();
        });
    }

});
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Show sequential messages in HTML</h1>
  <p>
  **Messages appears here instead of dialog**
  </p>
 </body>
```

Comment: You reeeeeeeeally need to read what HTML and AJAX is

Comment: I think what he's asking is to have a HTML overlay, rather than an alert dialog. Evident as he phrases it as 'How can I do the **same thing** but in HTML but not JavaScript dialog?'

Comment: @remyabel Yes. That's what exactly I was trying to ask. Sorry about my poor explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `showComments` function, replace this line:

```
alert(comment.message);
```

Into these:

```
var messages = $('p').text();
$('p').text(messages + comment.message + "\n");

// Show for 5 seconds, then hide the `p` element.
$('p').show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
```

That way, it will fill the paragraph with the comment message(s).

Comment: Great answer! Thanks! what if I want it to appear only for 5 secs? and disappear?

Comment: If you want to have more control over your comments, you can change your markup a bit and append new elements for each comment.